# Is a subprocess required in the activiti diagram for this use case?

Tags: alfresco, activiti

**Use case Description:**
Person1 starts the workflow assigning user tasks to multiple assignees (parallelly) , similarly, those assignees assign user task to multiple assignees.

**Confusion:** 
Is a subprocess required for this case?

[image: Activity Diagram Designed by me]

Answer (score 4):

First of all i don't think the diagram you provide is a valid BPMN definition, you can't make a sequence flow that goes to a start event.

> Is a subprocess required for this case?

It's not **required** but you can use it. the main reasons to use a sub-process:

- **For clarity purposes:** sub-processes make it easier to communicate you process to your clients.
- **Reusability :** You can reuse the sub-process logic in another process.
- **Events seperation :** When creating a sub-process you are also creating a new scope for events.
- **Looping* :** You can make your sub-process repeating until it reaches a specific a condition, just like a looping task.
- **Multiple instances* :** You can use sub-process when you want to allow multiple execution in parallel.

P.S: **Looping** and **Multiple instances** are techniques that are also achievable using simple tasks, but if the process is fairly complex, using sub-process will be a better approach for maintenance and clarity reasons.

Comment: I would take out looping and multiple instances bullets as they don't make a valid argument (both are available on tasks as well), and would add possibility of reusing a sub-process

Comment: Looping and multiple instances are techniques that are also available for simple tasks, but the advantage of using sub-processes over simple tasks in the case of a fairly complex process, is clarity.
Reusability is good point though.
I edited my answer, thank you.